# Random Swap position of 16 buttons

Tags: java, android

I have to make a find dublicate game sample for school, I have 16 buttons with each2 buttons have same image. But the problem is, I want to randomely set position of that 16 buttons when I opened the game.
Anyone help me please!

Mycode is

```
ImageButton bt1, bt2, bt3, bt4, bt5, bt6, bt7, bt8, bt9, bt10, bt11, bt12, bt13, bt14, bt15, bt16;

    int arraypic[]={R.drawable.elephant,R.drawable.giraffe,R.drawable.hog,R.drawable.lion,R.drawable.monkey,R.drawable.panda,R.drawable.pig,R.drawable.tiger};
    int button []= {R.id.bt1, R.id.bt2,R.id. bt3,R.id. bt4,R.id.bt5, R.id.bt6, R.id.bt7,R.id.bt8,R.id. bt9, R.id.bt10, R.id.bt11,R.id. bt12,R.id. bt13,R.id. bt14, R.id.bt15,R.id. bt16};
    Random random = new Random();
    int rr= random.nextInt(button.length);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingame);
        bt1 = findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        bt2 = findViewById(R.id.bt2);
        bt3 = findViewById(R.id.bt3);
        bt4 = findViewById(R.id.bt4);
        bt5 = findViewById(R.id.bt5);
        bt6 = findViewById(R.id.bt6);
        bt7 = findViewById(R.id.bt7);
        bt8 = findViewById(R.id.bt8);
        bt9 = findViewById(R.id.bt9);
        bt10 = findViewById(R.id.bt10);
        bt11 = findViewById(R.id.bt11);
        bt12 = findViewById(R.id.bt12);
        bt13 = findViewById(R.id.bt13);
        bt14 = findViewById(R.id.bt14);
        bt15 = findViewById(R.id.bt15);
        bt16 = findViewById(R.id.bt16);

        bt1.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[1]);
        bt2.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[1]);
        bt3.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[2]);
        bt4.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[2]);
        bt5.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[3]);
        bt6.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[3]);
        bt7.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[4]);
        bt8.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[4]);
        bt9.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[5]);
        bt10.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[5]);
        bt11.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[6]);
        bt12.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[6]);
        bt13.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[7]);
        bt14.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[7]);
        bt15.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[0]);
        bt16.setBackgroundResource(arraypic[0]);
```

Comment: Why not setting the images randomly instead of the buttons?

Comment: instead of changing positions of buttors, you should change images on buttons randomly. Shuffle the 0..15 array, and set images to positions

Comment: Post your xml..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the most simple way is like follows, using [`List`s](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and the [`Collections.shuffle()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List) method:

```
// collect your resources in Lists
List<Integer> pics = Arrays.asList(R.drawable.elephant, R.drawable.giraffe, R.drawable.hog, R.drawable.lion, R.drawable.monkey, R.drawable.panda, R.drawable.pig, R.drawable.tiger);
List<Integer> buttonResources = Arrays.asList(R.id.bt1, R.id.bt2, R.id.bt3, R.id.bt4, R.id.bt5, R.id.bt6, R.id.bt7, R.id.bt8, R.id.bt9, R.id.bt10, R.id.bt11, R.id.bt12, R.id.bt13,R.id.bt14, R.id.bt15, R.id.bt16);
List<ImageButton> buttons = new ArrayList<ImageButton>();

// randomize order of the pictures
Collections.shuffle(pics);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingame);

    for(int i = 0; i < buttonResources.size(); i++)
    {
        ImageButton bt = findViewById(buttonResources.get(i));
        buttons.add(bt);

        bt.setBackgroundResource(pics.get(i/2)); // hack: integer division, works because the number of pictures is half the number of buttons
    }

    // access the buttons later like this:
    bt1 = buttons.get(0);
}
```

Using the `Collections.shuffle(list)` method randomizes the order of the pictures. Doing so lets you setBackgroundResouces sequentially.

In this way you will have all the button instances collected in a `List`. This enables you to use loops instead of manual listing of all buttons. If you want to acces a single button later on, use the index access `buttons.get(index)`.

Comment: this works, sir.. your code is shuffling pics, I changed it to shuffle buttons. Still one more question, I want to make if two same buttons are clicked one after another, the will be positive value, else in the second click if the user click wrong pic, there will be negative value. Please help me. I am a junior student. And am just starting to learn. Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: Now you're asking a different topic. Basically one would declare a member variable which gets set a value by the buttons' click function. The second click checks the stored value and initiates further functionality as well as resetting the member's state. See also [Wikipedia's example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_programming#A_trivial_event_handler) as an entry point

Answer (score 0):

Sample code, for your problem:

```
Integer arraypic[]={R.drawable.elephant,R.drawable.giraffe,R.drawable.hog,R.drawable.lion,R.drawable.monkey,R.drawable.panda,R.drawable.pig,R.drawable.tiger};
int button []= {R.id.bt1, R.id.bt2,R.id. bt3,R.id. bt4,R.id.bt5, R.id.bt6, R.id.bt7,R.id.bt8,R.id. bt9, R.id.bt10, R.id.bt11,R.id. bt12,R.id. bt13,R.id. bt14, R.id.bt15,R.id. bt16};
List<Integer> randomList = randomizedList(arraypic);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ingame);
    bt1 = findViewById(R.id.bt1);
    bt2 = findViewById(R.id.bt2);
    bt3 = findViewById(R.id.bt3);
    bt4 = findViewById(R.id.bt4);
    bt5 = findViewById(R.id.bt5);
    bt6 = findViewById(R.id.bt6);
    bt7 = findViewById(R.id.bt7);
    bt8 = findViewById(R.id.bt8);
    bt9 = findViewById(R.id.bt9);
    bt10 = findViewById(R.id.bt10);
    bt11 = findViewById(R.id.bt11);
    bt12 = findViewById(R.id.bt12);
    bt13 = findViewById(R.id.bt13);
    bt14 = findViewById(R.id.bt14);
    bt15 = findViewById(R.id.bt15);
    bt16 = findViewById(R.id.bt16);

    bt1.setBackgroundResource(randomList.get(0));
    bt2.setBackgroundResource(ramdomList.get(1));
    ....
    bt16.setBackgroundResource(randomList.get(31));
}

public List<Integer> randomizedList(Integer []objs) {
    List<Integer> initial = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(objs));
    initial.addAll(Arrays.asList(objs));
    List<Integer> randomList = new ArrayList<>();
    Random rand = new Random ();
    for(int i=0; i<objs.length;i++) {
        int r = rand.nextInt(initial.size());
        randomList.add(initial.get(r));
        initial.remove(r);
    }
    return randomList;
}
```

The `randomizedList` method takes in the array of image resource values as its parameter. It creates a list out of the array, with two copies of every array element in the list.

It then randomly takes an index, puts the element at that index into `randomList`, and removes it from the original list.